# How to align multiple <span> inside <li>

Tags: html, css

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7s2af/)

How could I align these checkmarks so they are in same line, one under another, right after the longest option from the left side.

```
<ul class="list-line-bold list-unstyled">
<li>Option 1: Unlimited</li>
<li>Option 123312: <span class="check"></span>
</li>
<li>Option 134: <span class="check"></span>
</li>
<li>Option 1: <span class="check"></span>
</li>
<li>Option 1423423423423: <span class="check"></span>
</li>
```

```
.list-unstyled {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.check {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/AfPGFCp.png);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: add float: right;  to you check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
.list-unstyled {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.check {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/AfPGFCp.png);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:right;
}
li{
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could float the `.check` elements to the right and have a maximum width on the `li`

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/e8QXm/

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7s2af/1/)**</kbd>

give `width: 400px` to `<li>` and `float: right` to `.check`